# Add timer for images in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

i want to add timer for my images in javafx  for example first ,for about 3 seconds my first image  displayed then for about 5 second my second image displayed and after that nothing shown.any idea about that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) to update the `imageProperty` of an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html):

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ImageDisplayTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image image1 = new Image("...") ;
        Image image2 = new Image("...")  ;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image1)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image2)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(8), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), null))
                );
        timeline.play();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot . another question how can i add 2 images in each duration ?

Comment: Just create an additional `ImageView` and a `KeyValue` for its `imageProperty` in each `KeyFrame`. (The `KeyFrame` constructor takes an arbitrary number of `KeyValue`s.)

Comment: you mean  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image1),new KeyValue(imageViewAdditional.imageProperty(), image2)),
 - i add this but first image displayed

Comment: How to add a fade transition between images?

Comment: Create additional `KeyFrame`s and `KeyValue`s that manipulate the image view's opacity property.